# Installing Tailwind to Ruby on Rails 6 | The engine "node" is incompatible with this module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, yarnpkg, tailwind-css

When installing Tailwind-CSS, I ran this command

```
yarn add tailwindcss@npm:@tailwindcss/postcss7-compat postcss@^7 autoprefixer@^9
```

I got this error message, which tells me to update node to a compatible version.

```
**error** tailwindcss@2.1.2: The engine "node" is incompatible with this module. Expected version ">=12.13.0". Got "10.24.1"
```

So how do I update node properly?
I am using Ruby on Rails 6

**Update**

When I updated node, I ran into a subsequent problem. This is what I ran to update node

```
nvm install 12.22.1
```

Now when I try to install Tailwind-CSS, I get a different error message.

```
Command 'yarn' not found
```

So then I ran nvm use 10.24.1 and I am back to square one.

Comment: Ruby on rails has nothing to do with tailwind. It's about the node version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you install via yarn, append

```
--ignore-engines
```

So the full installation command is

```
yarn add tailwindcss@npm:@tailwindcss/postcss7-compat postcss@^7 autoprefixer@^9 --ignore-engines
```

I don't know why this works, but it does

Comment: It works because then you're ignoring the engine validation, which is what was complaining. Yarn wasn't found when you moved to a different version of Node because you hadn't installed it _for that version of Node_.